# Can you shift the position of a facet label or strip bar in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, r-forestplot

I'm using ggplot to graph a forest plot. I have used facet labels to label groups (in example below Test1, Test2, Test3). Is there a way to slightly shift the actual position of the facet label/strip to the left (as indicated by the arrows in my picture below)?

I can shift the position of the text within the facet label but I think I have done that as much as possible. Thus, I think I need to shift the actual facet label (strip bar/rectangle) itself. Is this possible?

Would be very grateful if anyone could help me or point out a way to get a similar effect!

[image]

Please find reproducible code here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(tidyverse)

# Reproducible dataset
df <- data.frame(outcome = c('outcome1', 'outcome1', 'outcome2','outcome2','outcome3','outcome3','outcome4','outcome4','outcome5','outcome5'),
                  type = c('Test1','Test1','Test2','Test2', 'Test3', 'Test3', 'Test3','Test3', 'Test3', 'Test3'),
                  Coef = c(0.10026935, 0.10026935, 0.13713358, 0.13713358,0.07753188,0.07753188,0.09193794,0.09193794,0.06170916,0.06170916),
                  CIr_low = c(0.070955475,0.070955475,0.108705781,0.108705781,0.052595474,0.052595474,0.056340327,0.056340327,0.036185918,0.036185918),
                  CIr_high = c(0.12958323,0.12958323,0.16556139,0.16556139,0.10246828,0.10246828,0.12753555,0.12753555,0.08723240,0.08723240),
                  model = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))

# Set type as factor
df <- df %>% mutate(type = fct_relevel(type, "Test1","Test2","Test3"))  

# Plot with ggplot 
ggplot(df, aes(x = outcome, y = Coef, ymin = CIr_low,ymax =CIr_high,fill = as.factor(type))) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(x=  outcome, ymin=CIr_low, ymax=CIr_high), width=0.2,cex=0.5)+
    geom_point(shape = 18, size = 5)+
    facet_grid(type ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed', col = 'black') +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.1, 0.25)) +
    ggforce::facet_col(facets = type ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free", strip.position = "top")+
    theme_bw()+
    coord_flip() +
    xlab('Group')+ 
    ylab(expression("Standardized" ~ beta *" (95%CI)"))+
    theme(line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.5), 
        plot.margin = margin(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, unit = "cm"),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white", fill="white"), 
        strip.text = element_text(colour = "black",face="italic"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12,angle = 0,hjust = 0,face="bold.italic", color="darkblue"),
        legend.position ="none", 
        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black"), 
        axis.line.y = element_blank(), 
        panel.border= element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines"), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black"), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),      
        axis.text=element_text( color = "black")  
     )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = outcome, y = Coef, ymin = CIr_low,ymax =CIr_high,fill = as.factor(type))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=  outcome, ymin=CIr_low, ymax=CIr_high), width=0.2,cex=0.5)+
  geom_point(shape = 18, size = 5, show.legend = F)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed', col = 'black') +
  scale_y_continuous(expression("Standardized" ~ beta *" (95%CI)"),limits = c(-0.1, 0.25))  + 
  xlab("")+
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_grid(type~., scales = "free", space = "free_y", switch = "y") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.y.left =  element_text(angle = 0,vjust = 1,size=12))
```

[image]

Or use a `cowplot` approach with `ggtitle`

```
plots <- df %>% 
  split(.$type) %>% 
  map2(.,names(.), ~ggplot(.x, aes(x = outcome, y = Coef, ymin = CIr_low,ymax =CIr_high,fill = as.factor(type))) +
        geom_errorbar(aes(x=  outcome, ymin=CIr_low, ymax=CIr_high), width=0.2, size=0.5)+
        geom_point(shape = 18, size = 5, show.legend = F)+
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed', col = 'black') +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.1, 0.25))+
        coord_flip() +
        xlab('')+ 
        ylab(expression("Standardized" ~ beta *" (95%CI)"))+
        ggtitle(.y)+
        theme_minimal(base_size = 12)+
        theme( panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
               panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              plot.title.position = "plot"))



cowplot::plot_grid(plots$Test1 +  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank()),
                   plots$Test2 +  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank()),
                   plots$Test3, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers Roman! I was hoping to get some overhang between the facet label and the y axes labels, as in reality, the text on the y axis is much longer than outcome1. I'll have a crack with this and see how both options look in the specific context I need it to work in. Thanks again!